# How to convert mongodb go driver's primitive.Timestamp type back to Golang time.Time type?

Tags: mongodb, go

mongo's go driver returns a bson timestamp as https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive#Timestamp  is there a way to convert it to `time.Time`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#timestamps

As you can see in mongodb official website, BSON Timestamps contains two values, `'T' for the seconds since Unix epoch` and `'I' for an incrementing ordinal for operations within a given second`.

So if you want to convert the bson timestamp to time.Time, you may just use `time.Unix(timestamp.T, 0)`

Answer (score 2):

Similarly to convert current time.Time to primitive.Timestamp type, we can use

```
primitive.Timestamp{T: uint32(time.Now().Unix()), I: 0}
```

Using **primitive.Timestamp** in mongo object modeling results in **Timestamp(1639732596, 0)** datatype in mongo collection. And when encoded to json, it results in object like :

> {
> "T": 1639732596,
> "I": 0
> }

In most of the use cases, it would be sufficient enough to use **time.Time** type for object model. This will result in **ISODate("2021-12-17T09:14:33.608Z")** datatype in mongo collection. And when encoded to json, results in string like :

> "2021-12-17T09:14:33.608Z"

Answer (score 0):

```golang
dateVal, _ := lastRecord["date"].(primitive.DateTime)
unixTime := int64(dateVal) / int64(time.Millisecond)
timeVal := time.Unix(0, unixTime*int64(time.Millisecond))

# or

result["date"].(primitive.DateTime).Time()
```