# Merge two MongoDB databases from old driver to official driver

Tags: mongodb, go

I am using go and I need to merge these two databases to keep the clients happy. I have changed the go code to use the official driver but it refuses to accept `time.Time`.
So in short, I need to transfer this model database

```
MgoResults struct {
        ID             bson.ObjectId  `bson:"_id"`
        ZipID          string         `bson:"zid"`
        Message        string         `bson:"message"`
        Result         string         `bson:"res"`
        Error          error          `bson:"errors"`
        ExpirationDate time.Time      `bson:"expirationDate"`
    }
```

into this model database

```
MgoResults struct {
        ID             primitive.ObjectID  `bson:"_id"`
        ZipID          string              `bson:"zid"`
        Message        string              `bson:"message"`
        Result         string              `bson:"res"`
        Error          error               `bson:"errors"`
        ExpirationDate primitive.DateTime  `bson:"expirationDate"`
    }
```

I don't have any strategies yet, but I welcome any examples with go code.
I have thought about iterating through all items and changing types then saving it to new model. Both databases work perfectly.

My main problem is during decoding and rebuilding the struct. I am probably doing something wrong.

```
    var v bson.M
    err = result.Decode(&v)

    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error at decode result : ", err)
    }
    //start filling the struct
    res.ZipID = v["zid"].(string)
    if v["errors"] == nil{
        res.Error = nil
    }else{
        res.Error = v["errors"].(error)
    }

    res.Message= v["message"].(string)
    res.ID      = v["_id"].(primitive.ObjectID)
    res.Result  = v["res"].(string)
    if v["expirationDate"] == nil{
        //res.ExpirationDate = time.Now()
    }else{
        res.ExpirationDate = v["expirationDate"].(time.Time )
        //res.ExpirationDate = v["expirationDate"].(primitive.DateTime)
    }
```

Comment: You should use `time.Time` with the official driver, it's supported.

Comment: Thanks, @icza, I was rushing to finish this. It actually works so far. So, I should be able to just use the new code on the old existing database?

Comment: Just replace `bson.ObjectId` with `primitive.ObjectID`, but `time.Time` should remain.

Comment: I already did.  Thanks.

Comment: I will try to investigate the source of this error, `"interface conversion: interface {} is primitive.DateTime, not time.Time"`

Comment: I am decoding my results to a `bson.M`. Somehow this is a problem. `var v bson.M; err = result.Decode(&v)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @icza and this slightly related answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64419437/2912740 .

I was able to modify my code a bit and it worked. So it looks like mongo returns its own `time` that needs some conversion to regular `time`.

```
mytime := v["expirationDate"].(primitive.DateTime)
res.ExpirationDate = mytime.Time()
```